# Comodo vs StartSSL: will the code signing authority affect ability of Java applets to run without security warnings?

Tags: java, applet, certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

We reviewed other posts on SO about code signing authorities, but none address our core concern: will using one code signing authority vs another affect the ability of an applet to run without security warnings? Right now, our applet prompts warnings about unsigned code, and we would like to avoid these warnings when the applet runs.

Price and other factors aside, will our Java applet work equally as well in all browsers regardless of which code signing authority we pick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> our applet prompts warnings about unsigned code, and we would like to avoid these warnings when the applet runs.

It's important to understand that those warnings are because the code is unsigned.  If it is signed, the text of the warnings will change.

> Price and other factors aside, will our Java applet work equally as well in all browsers regardless of which code signing authority we pick?

It depends on whether the Certification Authority has the status of already being in the Java 'trusted certificates key-store'.  My understanding is that Thawte and & Verisign (two of the more expensive ones) are, while some of the cheaper newer entrants into the field aren't.

For the latter group, the user will **first** be prompted to accept/import their certificate, before being prompted to accept your code.  For the more expensive ones, the user will only see one prompt for your signed code.

But the thing you need to be aware of is..

> ..affect the ability of an applet to run without security warnings?

**No** avenue will suppress **all** security warnings.  Those warnings are there for:

1. The protection of the end user.
2. Maintaining Java's reputation as a 'secure' plug-in.  So that people are willing to have the Java plug-in installed at all.

Comment: I think these OTT warnings will eventually have the opposite effect. Many Java users will habitually learn to ignore the hysteria, drop their security settings and permit the applications to run by as a matter of course.  Then Oracle will have to block all, unsigned applets and thus will stab themselves in the foot as Developers move to other technologies which do not cast aspersions on their software.

Comment: @AndrewS *"Then Oracle will have to block all, unsigned applets.."* Which would be noticed by about .1% of Java Developers. The major source of 'I want to make an applet' are newbies who are instructed to do so by their teacher.  And to that I say..  (stock comment follows) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: 1% did you just guess, lol? Not applets, JWS for an small scale university project shared with highschools. BTW the reason applets are bad in teaching is flawed design, a flawed design which evidences the point of my previous comment.

Comment: @AndrewS No, not 1%, but 1/10th of one percent.  And to be honest, the figure was 'plucked from the air' based on vast experience helping people with applets (most of whom were students who would later happily cast them aside, never to think upon them again).  But since you challenged me, I did a (tiny) bit of research.  There are 689,900 Java questions on SO.  There are 5,900 Applet questions.  That ratio is more than 100 to one.  And, as I alluded, being the [top provider of answers in regard to applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers), most of them (I'd say at least 20 to 1)..

Comment: .. are newbies (who do not understand the class-path, how the applet element in HTML works, what a `ClassNotFoundException` means, how to go about debugging an applet..).

Comment: Oracle has blocked unsigned apps now.  Very irritating since that means we now need to shell out $$$ for a certificate to run our internal only software from our own trusted servers.  Even then, we have periodic issues with certain machines/browsers failing to properly recognize the certificates.  While I understand Oracle's reason, it's making me look at other technologies to replace Java in the future here.